# Getting syntax error, unexpected end-of-input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, syntax-error

I keep getting a syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, despite checking the code, and even after removing the code and running it the problem seems to not be solved.here is the code :

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController

before_filter :authenticate_user!

def new
    @booking = Booking.new
end

def create
    @booking = current_user.booking.create(booking_params)
    if @booking.save
        flash[:alert] = "You have now booked a date"
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        flash[:alert] = "Error:booking did not save"
        redirect_to root_path
        render 'new'
    end
end


def show
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
end

def edit
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])

    unless @booking.user == current_user
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end

def update 
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
    unless @booking.user == current_user
        redirect_to root_path

    if @booking.update_attributes(booking_params)   
        redirect_to root_path
        flash[:notice] = "You have edited your post"
    else
        render 'edit'
        flash[:alert] = "something went wrong"
    end
end

def destroy 
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
    @booking.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
end 

private
def booking_params
    params.require(:booking).permit(:content)
end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you missed `end` keyword here

```
def update 
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
    unless @booking.user == current_user
        redirect_to root_path
    end # <~~~ missed in your code
    if @booking.update_attributes(booking_params)   
        redirect_to root_path
        flash[:notice] = "You have edited your post"
    else
        render 'edit'
        flash[:alert] = "something went wrong"
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you!! It worked, I thought "unless" would be part of the "if and "else" statement and not need a separate end.

Answer (score 2):

Bogus `update` method; you're missing an `end` of the `current_user` check.

**Also** redirect does *not* stop executing code, you need to return.

Answer (score 1):

Actual error - missed `end` after `unless` condition.

You can even refactor your code like this

```
def update 
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to root_path unless @booking.user == current_user
    if @booking.update_attributes(booking_params)   
        redirect_to root_path
        flash[:notice] = "You have edited your post"
    else
        render 'edit'
        flash[:alert] = "something went wrong"
    end
end
```